# warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules (even for void pointers)

Tags: c++

Following code gives error when compiled with gcc version 4.1 and with -O2 flag. It compiles fine with gcc version 4.4, 4.5 etc.

The error is:
    `warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules`

```
void foo(void **a = NULL);

int main()
{
    int *a;
    foo((void **)&a);  //I get above error here

    cout << "a[0] " << *a << endl;
    cout << "a[1] " << *(a+1) << endl;
    cout << "a[2] " << *(a+2) << endl;
    return 0;
}

void foo(void **a)
{
    int  b[3];
    b[0] = 10; b[1] = 20; b[2] = 35;
    if(a != NULL) {
         *a = (char *)malloc(20);
         memcpy((char *)(*a),  &b, 12);
    }

}
```

---

Now to avoid this can I program like given below. Is this is good solution to avoid this warning? I am able to avoid this warning in this code.

```
void foo2(char **a = NULL);

int main()
{
    char *a; 
    float c[3];
    foo2(&a);
    memcpy(&c, a, sizeof(c));
    cout << "c[0] " << *c << endl;
    cout << "c[1] " << *(c+1) << endl;
    cout << "c[2] " << *(c+2) << endl;
    return 0;
}

void foo2(char **a)
{
    float  c[3];
    c[0] = 10.123; c[1] = 2.3450; c[2] = 435.676;
    if(a != NULL) {
        *a = (char *)malloc(sizeof(c));
        memcpy((char *)(*a),  &c, sizeof(c));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is complaining that you are passing using a cast an `int **` to a function accepting `void **` and by the standard the compiler is not required to check that writes made through a `void **` could affect an object of type `int *`.

An `int *` and a `void *` are different types and the compiler is not required to check about possible aliasing between them. As a practical concrete example consider:

```
int *a = &one_thing;
void **b = (void **)&a;
bar(a);
(*b) = &other_thing;
baz(a); // Here the compiler may assume `a` didn't change
```

Note also that the standard guarantees you can convert any pointer to an object to a `void *` and back safely, but your code however converts an `int**` to `void**` and back: this is not the same thing and is not guaranteed to be safe.

The `memcpy` case is interesting because formally the function takes `void *` values and a `void *` cannot be used to dereference anything. IIUC it is however acknowledged that `memcpy` will read/write one (unsigned) `char` at a time and therefore the compiler is forced to assume that after a `memcpy` call objects of any type that have been potentially written over could now have a new value (there is a special rule in the standard that says that a `char *` and an `usigned char *` can alias values of any type).

So yes, using `memcpy` you can do any nasty thing you like around the type system and the compiler is not allowed to ignore/reorder your write operations. I've read somewhere that compilers even detect `memcpy` calls and actually generate reasonable code so only the syntax (not the performance) will be horrible.

Comment: I have some confusion about this. I will edit my question