# Casting small fields in a structure to a larger variable

Tags: c, struct, c89, strict-aliasing

I have a situation in a legacy code with a large field of a structure being split into two sub-fields. For example, a `uint32` is split into two `uint16`'s:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16 myVar_H;
    uint16 myVar_L;
} MyStruct;
```

Until now these fields were read from a `uint32` variable via shifting to read each `uint16` portion. Now we want to optimize this so that we read the entire `uint32` by casting the first field's address to a `uint32`:

```
MyStruct s;
*((uint32*)(&s.myVar_H)) = myValue;
```

This works for my compiler. The question is if this is legal and defined in C89 (or other C standards)?

Note: changing the structure is another option, but since this is an ancient legacy code based on a proprietary protocol I'd rather not touch the structures definition.

**Edit:** I am using a big-endian MCU (a ColdFire), so this works correctly in the endianess regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few problems with your "optimized" solution:

1. It violates the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).
2. It will not work on little-endian machines (the immense majority of computers nowadays), because you are not reordering correctly the high and low fields.
3. There is no guarantee that `myVar_H` and `myVar_L` are consecutive in memory: the compiler is allowed to add padding between the two fields.

The legal and platform-independant way of achieving what you want is to keep your previous solution with shifting. It shouldn't bring any performance issues.

```
MyStruct s;
// Reading
uint32 u = (uint32)s.myVar_H << 16 | s.myVar_L; // The cast is important
// Writing
s.myVar_H = myValue >> 16;
s.myVar_L = myValue % 0xFFFF;
```

---

**Edit following comment**: you say you work on big endian machines so memory order is not a problem. In that case, the "most legal" thing you may do is  make your struct a `union` with an anonymous struct (not actual `C89`, it's a `gcc` extension). This way you don't break strict aliasing and the new definition doesn't break any existing code.

```
typedef union // Your type is now a union
{
    struct
    {
         uint16 myVar_H;
         uint16 myVar_L;
    }; // Anonymous struct, legal C11 but gcc extension in C89

    uint32 myVar;
} MyStruct;

s.myVar = myValue; // Safe
```

Comment: Incidentally, I am using a big-endian MCU (a ColdFire), so that's okay. Padding is a risk, of course, which can be resolved by forcing a padding size of 1 (via a pragma).

Comment: @presiuslitelsnoflek After reading some more on strict aliasing, I understand that the aliasing problem is referring to the `uint16` as a `uint32`, right? It's not that I include both fields in the cast to a `uint32` - this is a side effect of the cast, is it not?

Comment: @Eli That's right, they are not *compatible* types. The fact that both fields are included is indeed "only" a side effect, but precisely the kind of side effects that led to the invention of the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: The `union` version breaks the aliasing rules just the same as OP's original code did. I don't see that it gains anything over OP's version. (Of course, your original suggestion of using arithmetic is the best one, and the compiler SHOULD generate optimal code from it anyway)

Comment: @Matt That's right, in theory the `union` also breaks aliasing and is UB according to the standard. However, since the OP is willing to take other risks (assuming big endianness and absence of padding), and since [the union trick is well defined under GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html#Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation), I thought this would be a more or less acceptable solution under OP's constraints.

Answer (score -2):

Regarding your specific question:

> The question is if this is legal and defined in C89?

the answer is ***no***: it violates the strict aliasing rule. See [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). The compiler is free to do whatever it wants, including completely ignoring the statement:

```
   *((uint32*)(&s.myVar_H)) = myValue;
```

A safer approach is to use `memcpy`; your code snippet becomes:

```
   MyStruct s;
   memcpy(&s.myVar_H, &myValue, sizeof myValue);
```

Of course, in this particular instance, `&s.myVar_H` is the same as `&s`.

This assumes `myValue` has to have the right size and format (e.g. it can't be a `char` or a `float`). It this is not the case, and if you have C99's compound literals, you can write:

```
   memcpy(&s.myVar_H, (uint32[]){myValue}, sizeof(uint32));
```

This is ugly, but you can hide its ugliness in a macro:

```
   #define LEGACY_CPY32(dst, src) memcpy(&(dst), (uint32[]){src}, sizeof(uint32))
```

But these suggestion will avoid ***only*** the strict-aliasing issue. Litte-endian problems and structure padding problems will still be present, and your code could break if you switch machines and/or compilers, or even just change compiler switches.

---

***Update #1***: Of course no one would ever write new code like this. But I am assuming the OP's goal is to update *working, legacy* code with the ***minimal*** number of changes, rather than doing a complete rewrite.

See also:

- [C aliasing rules and memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275353/c-aliasing-rules-and-memcpy) (which I don't understand)
- [warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules (even for void pointers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676060/warning-dereferencing-type-punned-pointer-will-break-strict-aliasing-rules-eve)

---

***Update #2***: Maybe I can present a more convincing case? For any construct, one can argue in terms of:

- legality
- efficiency
- elegance

For the third criteria, *elegance*, my suggestion loses hands down, compared with e.g. union punning.

For the second criteria, *efficiency*, John Regehr in [Embedded in Academia, "Type Punning, Strict Aliasing, and Optimization"](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/959) (June 2013) states regarding a similar issue:

> Compilers such as GCC 4.8.1 and Clang ~3.3 (both for x86-64 Linux) fail to generate good code for `c2` [an example of the type punning feature of unions] ... [and give] crappy object code

whereas in his example `c5` which uses `memcpy`:

> Both compilers understand `memcpy` deeply enough that we get the desired [optimal] object code.
>
> In my opinion `c5` is the easiest code to understand out of this little batch of functions because it doesn't do the messy shifting and also it is totally, completely, obviously free of complications that might arise from the confusing rules for unions and strict aliasing. It became my preferred idiom for type punning a few years ago when I discovered that compilers could see through the `memcpy` and generate the right code.

Finally, let us look at the first criteria, *legality*. Regehr states regarding union punning (*emphasis* added):

> Unfortunately this code [`c2`, using union punning] is also *undefined* by modern C/C++ dialects (or maybe just *unspecified*, I'm not totally sure).

I am reluctant to disagree with Regehr, but the consensus on Stack Overflow seems to be that union punning has been valid since C99; see:

- [Is type-punning through a union unspecified in C99, and has it become specified in C11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639947/is-type-punning-through-a-union-unspecified-in-c99-and-has-it-become-specified)
- [Correct way for interpreting one type as another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655147/correct-way-for-interpreting-one-type-as-another)

But it was *not* defined behavior in C89, which the OP specifically asks about.

Finally note the OP requests that:

> Since this is an ancient legacy code based on a proprietary protocol I'd rather not touch the structures definition

The `memcpy` solution leaves the header files untouched, which is advantageous if you are working with a team of touchy programmers. And you can easily back out all of your changes by redefining the macro `LEGACY_CPY32` to be the previous "incorrect"-but-working functionality:

```
 #define LEGACY_CPY32(dst, src) (*((uint32*)(&(dst))) = (src))
```

Comment: How do you account for padding in the struct across different compilers and hardware platforms? Note, I've downvoted for your use of the word "safest." Had you not included this, I wouldn't have downvoted. As it stands, this is outright incorrect. Please see presius's answer.

Comment: @SanJacinto: Thank you for your suggestion; I've edited my answer. And I believe presius's answer is backwards.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey: Why does this avoid anti-aliasing issues? The behavior seems similar - basically treat `&s.myVar_H` as a pointer to a `uint32` or to 4 bytes. The "danger" of referring to two consecutive `struct` fields as a single field is the same.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey Agreed, he had it backwards but the semantics were correct. I still don't like your solution. There's nothing inherently "unsafe" about bit shifting and byte arithmetic other than human error. Your solution includes built-in problems and isn't really much of a solution.

Comment: Your `memcpy` variation still has the same aliasing problem, just in a different form. You read bytes which were stored as one type, via an lvalue of a different type. It is no better or worse than the original.  (In cases where there are alignment concerns, the memcpy version is "better" in that it avoids alignment problems, however both versions still violate the aliasing rules)

Comment: BTW, `(uint32*)(&s.myVar_H)` can be replaced by `(uint32*)&s` everywhere - structs are guaranteed to have no initial padding

Comment: @MattMcNabb: (to the BTW) Of course. And I _do_ say this. But I'm assuming that the OP is just giving us a toy example, and that his real code is much more complicated.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: (to your first comment) What you are saying appears the similar to the question [C aliasing rules and memcpy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3275353), in which the OP says that `memcpy` _is_ ok, and asks _why_? But he doesn't get a good answer, I think, even from a 200K user.

Comment: The `memcpy` itself doesn't break the rule *yet*, but the rule is broken when you access the value via the expression `p`, in that example. The top answer addresses this with "as long as you don't access p afterwards" and " that might cause undefined behavior depending on the bitpattern". The standard description of that is "accessing an object via an lvalue not of compatible type", or something similar. It is still aliasing the same bytes in both cases, just in the `memcpy` case the bytes were moved before they were read by an lvalue expression of the same type in both cases.